# Wordpress and vanilla session never timeout?

Tags: wordpress, timeout, mediawiki

I deploy wordpress, vanilla and mediawiki in same server, after a long time, mediawiki has timeout but wordpress and vanilla is still on. Why? is that the wordpress and vanilla designed to never timeout?

Comment: Did you check off "remember me" when logging in? Look at the cookies in your browser.

Comment: no. And I test the http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki, this site also not timeout after a whole night

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by long time... If the elapsed time is higher than the configured [cookie expiration time](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCookieExpiration), that's intentional.

If not, you might have an issue with session handling. Often, it's a misconfigured [memcached](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Memcached). Disable memcached in your LocalSettings.php if you enabled it and you're not 100 % sure you configured it correctly.